# Apple Pay Checkout Integration?

Tags: cartthrob

I would like to use Apple Pay in my checkout through Stripe. Is this possible and if so, is there any documentation to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector; we run CartThrob)

My understanding is that right now Apple Pay is only used for within-app purchases, not on mobile websites. So typically this would be unrelated to the website's CartThrob installation. Or is the app just a wrapper for the site?